# how to redirect my app to from one page to another page without loosing my id and password in android

Tags: android, redirect, httpclient

currently i am working on SMS project using our own SMS gateway.
I used HttpClient to connect my home page of SMS gateway.successfully login but 
on next page I have to send SMS but when i call next post request old id and password are lost.
I got home screen in response.
Any one help me to get success message.

Comment: use shared preferences to save data

Comment: Option above shall serve your needs. However, if you're looking to preserve credentials only while you're in activity, use application class. It'll maintain values until application is closed by the user or android kills the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same httpClient to be able to control the session correctly.

Try these steps, referring to a generic `LoginActivity`

```
public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
```

Initialize it for the first time as follows.

```
URL url=new URL(urlToHit);
LoginScreen.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); //LoginScreen is the name of the current Activity
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
HttpResponse response = LoginScreen.httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

Now for all further connections I used the same httpClient For example in the next activity.

```
URL url=new URL(urlToHit);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
HttpResponse response = LoginScreen.httpClient.execute(httppost);
```

I haven't tested this, but I remember i had to face the same problem and i solved it storing the httpClient and using always that one.

Source: http://www.lightrains.com/blog/simple-tip-session-handling-android

Comment: thank's for providing your help. +1 for making httpclient glob

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual flux it should be doing? Where do you set this id and password? Do you have the server and the web in the same server?
I think the question is a little undefined and the title could be very different from your real problem.

Check this in case it might help you [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

use Bundle for this,just like

```
Intent in = new Intent(current.this,destination.class);
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("ID", "3");    
bundle.putString("PASSWORD", "home");   
in.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(in);
```

and you can get this in destination activity like

```
      Bundle selected = getIntent().getExtras();
      id= selected.getString("ID");
      password  = selected.getString("PASSWORD");
```

Comment: i dont want to send it to activity. i wont to send it to some url using httpclient